# How to hide react component files in react from the browser?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am making a web application with front-end in react and back-end in Node.js. I am trying to implement role-based functionality, and I do not want users to see all the available components. For example, components for the admin tools are in component files which any user can see through the console as the browser has all the js files, but I do not want normal users to see the functionalities admin have. What can be a way to hide these components and only allow the browser to download these component files if the user role is admin.

Comment: Won't you be using a production build?

Comment: you would have to dynamically load these components

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I will be using production build but would it not download all my javaScript files in the start? For example, if the user is on the login page, then do browser have all the components downloaded.

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I am not talking about loading the components on the front end. I am concerned about the javaScript files that people can see on the browser. I do not want the normal user to see component files admin have. Do you understand the question? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think server side rendering (SSR) might be the best option here. That way the content is sent from the server (safe place) and then loaded on the client after the fact.

https://www.google.com/search?q=server+side+rendering+in+react&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS769US769&oq=server+side+rendering+in+react&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.8253j0j4&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

You can also checkout a framework like Next.js which I believe does SSR out of the box.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks